# Validate assertion after request replay attack

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2, nemlogin

I have tried to do a replay attack on my own integration of nemlog-in 3 authentication, but i'm having trouble figuring out how to implement protection against it. I have intercepted the request to my assertion endpoint, after login on the IdP, and then saved the SAML response for later use.

If i login again and replace the SAML response in my new assertion request with the old SAML response, then i'm still getting authenticated. I expected to get rejected, since it's old and have already been used. Do you have built in protection against replay attacks in your saml2 NuGet package or do i have to keep track of received SAML responses myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable replay validation `DetectReplayedTokens` (default disabled) https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Configuration/Saml2Configuration.cs#L55

**.NET Core / .NET 5**

And set the `TokenReplayCache` / implement the `ITokenReplayCache` https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Configuration/Saml2Configuration.cs#L48

**.NET Framework**

And set the `TokenReplayCache` / implement the `IdentityModelCaches`
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Configuration/Saml2Configuration.cs#L45
and set the `TokenReplayCacheExpirationPeriod`
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Configuration/Saml2Configuration.cs#L46